# Can parents force you to do alima classes?

Tags: parents, knowing-islam

I don't want to become and alima or do the classes because I feel I can't keep up with it. But my parents say they will put me in no matter what. Are they allowed to do that ???

( I dont wanna disrespect them I just hope they can understand )

Comment: Why do you feel that you can't keep up with it? If you just ponder about it, you will know that it has enormous benefits in this world, and more importantly, in hereafter.
Allaah says in Qur'an 2:216 "But perhaps you hate a thing and it is good for you; and perhaps you love a thing and it is bad for you. And Allah Knows, while you know not."
This verse is specifically for fighting but its general meaning applies to other things as well.

Answer (score -1):

No they cannot force you to study alima. Islam doesn't force anyone to do anything against their will. Of course you should learn about Islam's law and follow. It doesn't mean you will only be a better muslim if you study Alima, you will be a better muslim IF you know Islam, studying alima is not the only way to know islam. You can read Quran, hadith, watch preaching and debate and improve you knowledge.

Forcing you to do Alima will only make you hate it. Of course you can try it and do better in alima, but don't force yourself if you absolutely don't want to do it. But don't stop learning Islam because you don't do alima.

Alima is for learning Islam's shariah, Quran, hadidh, Arabic knowledge, etc. If you can do it by yourself you do it. But don't hate alima because you have to be under strict muslim environment. Only under strict environment can you be obedient and learn better.